# Javascript URL redirect not working

Tags: javascript, django, redirect

I have a search function here:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter keywords..">
    <button onclick="search_click();">Search</button>
</form>
```

`search_click()` is defined as follows:

```
function search_click(){
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

However, every time I click the button, it just reloads the current page and appends a '?' to the end of the URL if it wasn't already there.  I've tried doing `window.location.href` also, but that doesn't work either.  If I just replace that line with `alert('test');`, it does show a popup, so I know it's executing.  What's wrong with my code?  Or is this a problem with Django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form is actually submitting causing your Javascript to be ignored.  Prevent the default event using the following script:

```
function search_click(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter keywords..">
    <button onclick="search_click(event);">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be bad practice to use preventDefault() ?